# How to correctly import multiple unity module in single android app avoiding name conflict between different unity module in android studio?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin

I have already imported two unity module . Triangle module and cube module .

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.labinapp.triangle.UnityPlayerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.labinapp.cube.UnityPlayerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

here is my grade file configuration

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.labinapp.demoCode"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true



    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        merge 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so'
        merge 'lib/x86/libmain.so'
        merge 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libunity.so'
        merge 'lib/x86/libunity.so'
        merge 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono.so'
        merge 'lib/x86/libmono.so'
    }


}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    compile project(':CubeModule')
    compile project(':TriangleModule')
}
```

I was facing some name conflicts which i solved by using merge

```
 packagingOptions {
        merge 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so'
        merge 'lib/x86/libmain.so'
        merge 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libunity.so'
        merge 'lib/x86/libunity.so'
        merge 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono.so'
        merge 'lib/x86/libmono.so'
    }
```

My problem is irrespective of any button i click only one unity project open 
this depends on order in which i place the dependency

> case 1:

```
   compile project(':CubeModule')
   compile project(':TriangleModule')
   -------------------------------------------------
   Output: CubeModule will be called by default
```

> case 2:

```
  compile project(':TriangleModule')
  compile project(':CubeModule')
  ---------------------------------------------------
  Output: TriangleModule will be called by default
```

I guess merge is not working properly is there any other way or any workaround to solve this problem any suggestion will  be helpful .

Comment: Have you find any solutions? please share..

Comment: Have you find any solutions? please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple things but failed . It seems impossible . Its like trying to keep two file in the same folder .But the problem is both the file has same name . You cannot use two module as both the modules comes with few common files which has to be placed in common folder .So based on the order of your dependency android build system picks one of them and pack it in apk.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you are calling UnityPlayerActivity.class from both the buttons - which is the default name given to Activity in Unity built code. The way to work this around is by renaming the java class in the Unity exported Android Projects.

> Before you build CubeModule and TriangleModule, check the Class
>   name and refactor it to another name. Don't forget to rename that name
>   in Android Manifest as well.

Now when you bring it into you app code, you will be refer to those class name and initiate particular unity modules correctly.